# How to configure varnish with mod_pagespeed for magento

Tags: varnish

I installed mod_pagespeed on my dedicated server.
but when i configure varnish on this server i got error max age should to be 1.
I need to know that can we use both varnsih and mod_pagespeed on same url.
Like can it both work well if both are working on server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As well as installing mod_pagespeed you need to set it up correctly:

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/downstream-caching

You will also have to make sure your version of mod_pagespeed supports 'Varnish' as this is currently an 'experimental feature'.

Answer (score -1):

I dont see any good reasoning to have both. They do pretty much the same thing, which one to choose - i think it's more of a taste preference.

[According to Varnish guys](https://www.varnish-cache.org/about) you'll be able to speed up delivery by 300x-1000x factor, which seems a little suspicious to me. The numbers are to unreal.

Accroding to [this PageSpeed Module Results](https://www.hyperlinksmedia.com/learning-center/seo/what-is-pagespeed-module/) article, you can cut loading times and data size by up to 90%, which would be equivalent to 10x factor. And this number is still ridiculously drastic improvement, however seems more realistic.

Personally, I'm mod_pagespeed fan, and, considering the fact, that I have seen numbers get cut down by 50%-90% in my own tests, I would go with MPS rather than Varnish.

Comment: Pagespeed doesn't cache anything but optimizes html for better delivery in browser. Varnish is a server side caching system. They are both completely different.